# check array for similar elements and transfer to new array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have an assignment where I have to create 3 arrays. The first two arrays have similar elements and the third is empty.

```
const int arraySize = 4;
array k[arraySize] = {1, 2 ,3, 7}
array j[arraySize] = { 1, 2, 8, 9}
array u;

int *ptr1 = arrayk;
    int *ptr2 = arrayj;
```

How could I compare the elements in the first two and then copy over those duplicates to the third empty array (array `u`)?

I was thinking something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++1) {
    for(int k = 0; k < arraySize; ++k) {
        if(&ptr1[i] == &ptr2[k]) {
            //copy elements that are duplicates to array u
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: I've added the homework tag since you mentioned _assignment_.

Comment: Your thinking looks right. Have you tried it?

Comment: Added homework tag for OP mentioning this is an "assignment".

Comment: yah i just not sure how to copy the duplicates to the array u.

Comment: the other arrays seem sorted. is this always the case?

Comment: Can an array have the same value twice, or is any particular value in an input array going to be unique? I.e. is `{1, 1, 3, 5}` a valid array?

Comment: Is it a requirement to copy the duplicates into an array?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore how would you use `std::copy_if` here? as in `std::copy_if(k, k + arraySize, u, [](int const& e1) { return std::find(j, j + arraySize, e1) != j + arraySize; });` ? If so, that's still a double loop and `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like homework, I'm assuming you want to do it by yourself not by using a library to achive this. This being the case, your code is fine, you just have to keep an integer variable to store the next available position in u array.

```
const int arraySize = 4; 
int next = 0; 
array k[arraySize] = {1, 2 ,3, 7};
array j[arraySize] = { 1, 2, 8, 9};
array u[arraySize]; // Because it at most be a copy of array k or j

for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
    for(int k = 0; k < arraySize; ++k) {
        if(arrayk[i] == arrayj[k]) {
            u[next++] = arrayk[i];
        }
    }
}
```

This way, when you find a duplicate you assign it to the next available position on u and then increase the value of next by one.

Here is the pointer version, although I strongly recommend to avoid them in cases like this, and use them only when they are needed.

```
const int arraySize = 4; 
int next = 0; 
array k[arraySize] = {1, 2 ,3, 7};
array j[arraySize] = { 1, 2, 8, 9};
array u[arraySize]; // Because it at most be a copy of array k or j

int *ptr1 = arrayk;
int *ptr2 = arrayj;

for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
    for(int k = 0; k < arraySize; ++k) {
        if(*(ptr1 + i)  == *(ptr2 + k) {
            u[next++] = *(ptr1 + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has `O(n^2)` complexity, rather than `O(n log n)` that can be obtained with sorting both ranges and doing `set_intersection`.

Comment: ok this seems very reasonable but can you see my re-edit with the pointers. how can i re-incorporate what you just added with my pointers?

Comment: @rhalbersma I agree, but this does't lool like he needs the best code to do it, he needs to learn about arrays and how to use them.

Comment: @AjMunot Do you need to use the pointers? Because I think you should avoid them when not necessary.

Comment: exactly topo.. i added some pointers in my original post if you could take a look

Comment: @AjMunot you don't want `&`. That will give you the **address** of the pointers. You want `*` which gets you their **values by dereferencing**.

Comment: @kevlar1818 ok i see but can you show me exactly because replace the "&" with "*" gets me an error

Comment: @AjMunot This [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) is extremely informative. You need to format it like this: `*(ptr+5)` to get the value of the array at an offset of 5. This is in the link.

Comment: @AjMunot I edited my answer and added the pointer version. Sorry for the lateness I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the STL, I recommend [`set_intersection`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/). Here is the example used in this link:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  int first[] = {5,10,15,20,25};
  int second[] = {50,40,30,20,10};
  vector<int> v(10);                           // 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  vector<int>::iterator it;

  sort (first,first+5);     //  5 10 15 20 25
  sort (second,second+5);   // 10 20 30 40 50

  it=set_intersection (first, first+5, second, second+5, v.begin());
                                               // 10 20 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

  cout << "intersection has " << int(it - v.begin()) << " elements.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

If you can't use the STL, consider this code (also from the link).

> The behavior of this function template is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> template <class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2, class OutputIterator>
>   OutputIterator set_intersection ( InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
>                                     InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2,
>                                     OutputIterator result )
> {
>   while (first1!=last1 && first2!=last2)
>   {
>     if (*first1<*first2) ++first1;
>     else if (*first2<*first1) ++first2;
>     else { *result++ = *first1++; first2++; }
>   }
>   return result;
> }
> ```

Comment: not allowed to really use STLs. this is intro to c++ stuff. However the third array is mentioned to be 1-D and empty

Comment: Using 5 as a magic number is kind of a bad practice. Using `#DEFINE` for that would make sense.

Comment: @AjMunot Look at the link, and look at the "equivalent code" portion. I will add that to my answer.

Comment: If you want to be really fancy, you can finish with a shrink-to-fit on  `v`.

Comment: okay i will take a look at yours but i added some pointers if that helps. i just re-edited my code

Comment: Another note: pre-conditions for `std::set_intersection` are that both input ranges are **sorted**. Still the general case of doing two sorts + the intersection is `O(n log n)`, rather than the OP's `O(n^2)` algorithm.